# Proving $\mathbb{E}[\|\theta_* - \widehat{\theta}\|_2^2]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $y = X\theta_* + z$,  where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$, $\theta_* \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $z = \mathcal{N}(0,I) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and suppose $rank(X) = d$. Prove that if $\widehat{\theta} = \arg\min_{\theta} \|X\theta - y\|_2^2$, then
    \begin{align*}
 \mathbb{E}[\|\theta_* - \widehat{\theta}\|_2^2] = tr((X^{\top}X)^{-1})
 \end{align*}

I don't know where to start for this problem. I compute the value for $tr((X^{\top}X)^{-1})$ and find $\|\theta_* - \widehat{\theta}\|_2^2$ but at a loss of how to go forward.

Comment: Edited to add context..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're doing linear regression on white noise, 
\begin{equation}
 y = X\theta_{*} + z
\end{equation}
The best estimator is OLS in this case, i.e.
\begin{equation}
 \hat{\theta}
 =
 (X^T X)^{-1} X^T y
\end{equation}
So, your error becomes 
\begin{equation}
 \Vert \theta_* - \hat{\theta} \Vert^2
 =
 \Vert \theta_* - (X^T X)^{-1} X^T y \Vert^2
\end{equation}
But $y = X\theta_{*} + z$, so
\begin{equation}
 \Vert \theta_* - \hat{\theta} \Vert^2
 =
 \Vert \theta_* - (X^T X)^{-1} X^T ( X\theta_{*} + z) \Vert^2
\end{equation}
Hence
\begin{equation}
 \Vert \theta_* - \hat{\theta} \Vert^2
 =
 \Vert \theta_* - \theta_{*} - (X^T X)^{-1} X^T z \Vert^2
 =
 \Vert  (X^T X)^{-1} X^T z \Vert^2
\end{equation}
But 
\begin{equation}
 \Vert \alpha \Vert^2
 =
 \alpha^T \alpha
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 \Vert \theta_* - \hat{\theta} \Vert^2
 =
 \Vert \theta_* - \theta_{*} - (X^T X)^{-1} X^T z \Vert^2
 =
 \big( (X^T X)^{-1} X^T z \big)^T  \big( (X^T X)^{-1} X^T z \big)
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
 \Vert \theta_* - \hat{\theta} \Vert^2
 =
 z^T X (X^T X)^{-1}(X^T X)^{-1} X^T z
\end{equation}
But since $ \Vert \theta_* - \hat{\theta} \Vert^2$ is a scalar, then 
\begin{equation}
 \Vert \theta_* - \hat{\theta} \Vert^2
 =
 \text{trace } \Vert \theta_* - \hat{\theta} \Vert^2
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 \Vert \theta_* - \hat{\theta} \Vert^2
 =
 \text{trace } z^T X (X^T X)^{-1}(X^T X)^{-1} X^T z
\end{equation}
Now use trace $AB = $ trace $BA$
\begin{equation}
 \Vert \theta_* - \hat{\theta} \Vert^2
 =
 \text{trace }  X (X^T X)^{-1}(X^T X)^{-1} X^T zz^T
\end{equation}
One more time now 
\begin{equation}
 \Vert \theta_* - \hat{\theta} \Vert^2
 =
 \text{trace }   (X^T X)^{-1}(X^T X)^{-1} X^T zz^TX
\end{equation}
Now the expectation comes in 
\begin{equation}
 E \Vert \theta_* - \hat{\theta} \Vert^2
 =
 E \text{trace }   (X^T X)^{-1}(X^T X)^{-1} X^T zz^T X
\end{equation}
everything is constant except for $zz^T$, i.e
\begin{equation}
 E \Vert \theta_* - \hat{\theta} \Vert^2
 =
  \text{trace }   (X^T X)^{-1}(X^T X)^{-1} X^T Ezz^T X
\end{equation}
But $Ezz^T =  I$ so
\begin{equation}
 E \Vert \theta_* - \hat{\theta} \Vert^2
 =
  \text{trace }   (X^T X)^{-1}(X^T X)^{-1} X^T X
  =
  \text{trace }   (X^T X)^{-1}
\end{equation}

Comment: This is clear and precise, thanks a lot!